# How to make sure that if value is entered in one field other (accompanying) field/dropdown list must be filled/selected

Tags: javascript, validation

I have a form in which area must be entered and then its unit must be selected from a dropdown list. I'm using javascript validation for this but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
function check_admin_post_property()
{
 var area=document.post_property.property_area.value;
if(area != "")
{
    if(document.post_property.area_unit.value == "Select")
    {
        alert("Area unit must be selected");
        document.post_property.property_area.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

First line declares a variable and gets value entered by end user. Second line checks if the field is not equal to empty, means it has value. Fourth line checks if the value in drop down list is equal to Select because user must select proper area unit. If it is Select validation fails.
Basically what I want to do is entering area is not mandatory but if it is mandatory it must be accompanied with a unit.

Here is my markup:

```
<form name="post_property" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr><td>Other fields</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Property area:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="property_area" style="border:1px solid red;"><span style="color:red">*</span</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Area unit:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="area_unit">
                <option value="Select">Select</option>
                <option value="square_feet">Square feet</option>
                <option value="square_yards">Square yards</option>
                <option value="square_meter">Square meter</option>
                <option value="acre">Acre</option>
                <option value="hectare">Hectare</option>
            </select>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return check_admin_post_property()"></td>
</tr>
```

Mark up is not in formatted form because stackoverflow's markups are not working properly. Not even visible on my side.

I'm importing js with src attribute of script element. It is inside a folder named js with js filename post_property.js Inside that file there is a function check_admin_post_property() where the above code resides.
I can't post the full script and html file because if they (my workplace people) find out i'll be out of here (this website is one of the most checked at my work place). But i have posted the relevant part. If you need more info about it please tell me or point to some third party page where such thing has been done.

Comment: Please provide us with markup

Comment: can you please put up the full js? is the js present inside a function?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that its using `<input type='submit'>`. What you should be using is `<input type='button'>`. Here is the working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_admin_post_property() {
    var area=document.post_property.property_area.value;
    if(area != "")
    {
        if(document.post_property.area_unit.value == "Select")
        {
            alert("Area unit must be selected");
            document.post_property.area_unit.focus();
            return false;
        }
        else
            document.post_property.submit();
    }
    else {
        alert("Area must be entered.");
        document.post_property.property_area.focus();
    }
}
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="post_property" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr><td>Other fields</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Property area:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="property_area" style="border:1px solid red;"><span style="color:red">*</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Area unit:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="area_unit">
                <option value="Select">Select</option>
                <option value="square_feet">Square feet</option>
                <option value="square_yards">Square yards</option>
                <option value="square_meter">Square meter</option>
                <option value="acre">Acre</option>
                <option value="hectare">Hectare</option>
            </select>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td align="center"><input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return check_admin_post_property()"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```